# Why is my build failing when using parse framework with Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, xcode6.1

Bridging-Header.h

```
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
```

AppDelegate.swift

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?
    func application(application: UIApplication,
                       didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions:
                       [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        Parse.setApplicationId(
            "---",
            clientKey: "---"
        )
        return true
    }
    func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive
        //   state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions
        //   (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user
        //   quits the application and it begins the transition to the 
        //   background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle
        //   down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause
        //   the game.
    }
    func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data,
        //   invalidate timers, and store enough application state information
        //   to restore your application to its current state in case it is
        //   terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is
        //   called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }
    func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive
        //   state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the
        //   background.
    }
    func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the
        //   application was inactive. If the application was previously in the
        //   background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    }
    func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if
        //   appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }
}
```

**I get 4 match-O link errors.**

**My link binary with libraries section:**

```
AudioToolbox

CFNetwork

CoreGraphics

CoreLocation

libz.dylib

MobileCoreServices

Parse

QuartzCore

Security

StoreKit

SystemConfiguration
```

**Errors:**

```
Ld /Users/randyschriefer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/my-chore-v1-fzgmcywcibhivvbfxickdtpycest/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/my-chore-v1.app/my-chore-v1 normal armv7
    cd /Users/randyschriefer/Desktop/Maddie/iOS/my-chore-v1
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=7.1
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk -L/Users/randyschriefer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/my-chore-v1-fzgmcywcibhivvbfxickdtpycest/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/randyschriefer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/my-chore-v1-fzgmcywcibhivvbfxickdtpycest/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/randyschriefer/Desktop/Maddie/iOS/my-chore-v1 -filelist /Users/randyschriefer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/my-chore-v1-fzgmcywcibhivvbfxickdtpycest/Build/Intermediates/my-chore-v1.build/Debug-iphoneos/my-chore-v1.build/Objects-normal/armv7/my-chore-v1.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -dead_strip -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos -Xlinker -force_load -Xlinker /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/arc/libarclite_iphoneos.a -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/randyschriefer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/my-chore-v1-fzgmcywcibhivvbfxickdtpycest/Build/Intermediates/my-chore-v1.build/Debug-iphoneos/my-chore-v1.build/Objects-normal/armv7/my_chore_v1.swiftmodule -miphoneos-version-min=7.1 -framework AudioToolbox -framework CFNetwork -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreLocation -lz -framework MobileCoreServices -framework Parse -framework QuartzCore -framework Security -framework StoreKit -framework SystemConfiguration -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/randyschriefer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/my-chore-v1-fzgmcywcibhivvbfxickdtpycest/Build/Intermediates/my-chore-v1.build/Debug-iphoneos/my-chore-v1.build/Objects-normal/armv7/my-chore-v1_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/randyschriefer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/my-chore-v1-fzgmcywcibhivvbfxickdtpycest/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/my-chore-v1.app/my-chore-v1

Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_BFExecutor", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFUser.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(BFTask+Private.o)
      l_OBJC_$_CATEGORY_BFExecutor_$_Background in Parse(BFTask+Private.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_BFTask", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFUser.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFFile.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFNetworkCommandRunner.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFObject.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFPush.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFRetryingCommandRunner.o)
      l_OBJC_$_CATEGORY_BFTask_$_Private in Parse(BFTask+Private.o)
      ...
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_BFTaskCompletionSource", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFCommandCache.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFNetworkCommandRunner.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFObject.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(BFTask+Private.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFTaskHTTPRequestOperation.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Disregard. Just add bolts.framework.

Comment: It is OK to answer your own question, as others will benefit more that way. Please post your answer and once the timeout period is passed you can mark your answer as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I needed was to add bolts.framework

Answer (score 0):

Add MobileCoreServices.framework from your project in addition to these frameworks